# Planes in magnetism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin

What does it mean the "easy-plane"?
Also, may I ask you to give me a representative picture of the easy-plane antiferromagnet?
What is the difference with the easy-plane "canted" antiferromagnet?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is "it" in your first sentence? Where did you see this notion of "easy-plane"?

Answer (score 0):

If this is about the magneto-crystalline anisotropy of ferromagnets, it is usual to specify easy *directions* and hard *directions*. An easy plane would then be perpendicular to a hard direction in a crystal with uniaxial symmetry (but there would still be some anisotropy in the plane).

Antiferromagnets also have preferred spin directions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is a hard direction?

Comment: In magnetite which is cubic, at room temperature <111> is the easy direction of magnetization, <100>  is the hard direction of magnetization, <110>  is the intermediate direction of magnetization. One can see this in the magnetization curves for different directions. Just as an example.